# Redirecting pages from the root folder to a subfolder

Tags: redirect, rewrite, joomla, phpbb

I have a Joomla site in the root directory of my domain, and I have a forum at /forum subdirectory.

How can I redirect visitors from the main site to the forum, continuing to have the possibility to access the site from a link at the forum?

Example:

```
http://example.com
```

redirected to

```
http://example.com/forum
```

, but I can access the main site by the link

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want may be as simple as

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/forum
```